# Masonry + Infinite Scroll and PrettyPhoto Lightbox

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

This is a re-post,

I'm using Masonry plugin with infinite-scroll plugin on WordPress blog. I need to use PrettyPhoto Plugin on this blog. PrettyPhoto lightbox working fine, but when Masonry loads the next set of posts (infinite scroll plugin loads the next set of post when scroll down), PrettyPhoto stops working.

**Note: The theme I use has embedded lightbox**

I'm not a expert in jQuery so, here's the two scripts which use on the theme

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/89122367/plugins.js 

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/89122367/scripts.js

I need to use PrettyPhoto on this theme, Need some help from experts

Comment: Does the old images (loaded before Masonry plugin) works good after it load new content? If Yes then I brobably konw the solution and cause.

Comment: @bumerang Yes, you're correct (I think)...it happens when I scroll down..Prettyphoto works fine when page load, but when I scroll down and masonry loads the nest sets of posts (with infinite-scroll)..prettyphoto doesn't work with those new posts.
But the old lightbox(fancy box) which embedded with the template works fine

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it's not working is that `Prettyphoto` don't know that there are some new images to "take care of" :) . When new items are uploaded, they dont't have `Prettyphoto`  `bind`. I think, that the easiest way is to add detection of ajax request and then fire `Prettyphoto` on new images.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto(); // or any other way You use prettyPhoto
});
```

Put the abowe code to the head section of Your page, ie:

```
<script>
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto(); // or any other way You use prettyPhoto
    }); 
</script>
```

This Should help You

Comment: The think is that You have give my script before You include jQuery library, this is way my script is calling error. You need to load jQuery library first, so just put my code on the bottom of Your head, just before `</head>` to make sure it will work correctly.

Comment: Are You using FireBug? Or have You try to run this page in some IE? You have some JavaScript problems. If You solve them my solution will work, but for now becouse of this problems it won't work. As I can see Your not much familiar with JavaScript.

Comment: I can't see anything on my web site in IE :(   I know nothing about JavaScript, I was just play around. I don't know how to debug this JavaScript..Anyway, thanks for your help